# REACT-EXPORT-EXCEL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, exportar

estoy intentando de sacar un excel de un array de objetos que obtengo de una API.
El array de objetos que me llega es este;

```
0: Object { id: 328, userId: "5555", accountingDate: "2022-07-29T00:00:00.000+00:00", … }
​​
accountingDate: "2022-07-29T00:00:00.000+00:00"
​​
category: Object { id: 7, subCategories: null, name: "Electricidad" }
​​
ch4: 0
​​
co2: 0
​​
date: null
​​
description: null
​​
h2o: 584795
​​
id: 328
​​
n2o: 0
​​
subCategory: Object { id: 12, name: "Factura agua", alcance: 1 }
```

Es decir, tanto category como subcategory son un objeto.

Para crear el excel estoy poniendo este codigo;

```
export default function DownExcel(props) {
console.log(props.transactions)




        return (
            <ExcelFile element={<button>Download Data</button>}>
                <ExcelSheet data={props.transactions} name="Emisiones">
                    <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="category.name"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="date" value="accountingDate"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="sub"value="subCategory.name"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Agua" value='h2o'/>
                                {/* //  value={(col) => col.is_married ? "Married" : "Single"}/> */}
                </ExcelSheet>
            </ExcelFile>
        );
    }
```

Las columnas de category y subcategory me las deja en blanco, el resto me lo exporta sin problema,

alguna ayuda? gracias!!